# How to convert pcap data of Velodyne's VLP-16 to point cloud without using Veloview?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, pcap, lidar, d3dimage, lidar-data

I am new to LiDAR technology. From the Documentation I found that we can visualize LiDAR data using Veloview software. But my aim is to create a 3D image using .pcap file and process it further for object detection. Whole working is in Ubuntu 14.04. 
Can anyone provide me a good solution?

Answer (score 3):

Open 6 terminal tabs (`Ctrl + Shift + t`):

1st tab:

```
$ roscore
```

2nd tab (run your .pcap file):

```
$ rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=/path/to file.pcap
```

3rd tab: (create .bag file to visualize in Rviz)

```
$ rosrun rosbag record -O vlp_16.bag /velodyne_packets
```

4th. tab: (play your .bag file just created from 3rd. tab):

```
$ rosbag play vlp_16.bag
```

5th. tab: (to convert `velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan` to `/Pointcloud2` and `/LaserScan` topic to visualize in Rviz):

```
$ roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch
```

6th. tab: (fixed frame **MUST** be assigned to "velodyne")

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne
```

In Rviz:

To visualize `/scan` topic:

> Displays -> Add -> By topic -> LaserScan

To visualize `velodyne_points` topic:

> Displays -> Add -> By topic -> PointCloud2

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into using ROS and the point cloud library. There is a lot of support for this kind of processing using those. For pulling in the data form the VLP-16 you could use [this ROS package](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Point Cloud Library.

Compiling PCL is a bit tricky, but once you get it going, you can do quite a lot of point cloud analysis.

Follow the instructions here for the [LiDAR HDL Grabber](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/hdl_grabber.php#hdl-grabber). 
For your purpose, you will want to include the `<pcl/io/vlp_grabber.h>` along with the `<pcl/io/hdl_grabber.h>`. The vlp_grabber, basically uses the same hdl_grabber but supplies the vlp calibration parameters. Also in the main, you will want to instantiate a `pcl::VLPGrabber` instead of a `pcl::HDLGrabber`.

These few changes alone may not be enough to getting a fully functional grabber and viewer, but it is a start.

The example on PCL is for the `hdl_viewer_simple.cpp` but there is also a `vlp_viewer.cpp` also located in `visualization/tools/`. Check that out.

This is not an answer to fully solve your problem, but provide a path to a solution if you want to use PCL.

Comment: Can PCL be used to read any non velodyne PCAPs, from other Lidar manufacturers? If not, what other ways are there?